# JQuery slideDown function and display: block?

Tags: jquery

I made a menu using jQuery `slideDown` function, everything seems to work fine, but sometimes when you fast move on a button realisation sub-menu appears before `slideDown` effect.

Web tool shows it’s because `“display block”` applies faster than `height` becomes bigger.

Does anyone know a solution? Here is my code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var submenu = $("#sub-menu"),
      activeSlide = $("#active"),
      startPos = activeSlide.position().left;

  $("#parent").hover(
    function() {
      submenu.stop(true, false).slideDown( 600);
    },
     function() {
      submenu.stop(true, false).slideUp( 600);
    });

  $(".nav > li").mouseenter(function() {
    var nextPos = $(this).position().left + startPos;
    activeSlide.animate({left: nextPos}, 250);
  });

   $(".nav").mouseleave(function() {
    activeSlide.animate({left: startPos}, 250);
  });

});// end ready
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/Kuzyo/pen/xKiIr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you test this code.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var submenu = $("#sub-menu"),
      activeSlide = $("#active"),
      startPos = activeSlide.position().left;


  $("#parent").hover(
    function() {
      submenu.stop(true, true).slideDown( 600);
    },
     function() {
      submenu.stop(true, true).slideUp( 600);
    });

  $(".nav > li").mouseenter(function() {
    var nextPos = $(this).position().left + startPos;

    activeSlide.stop().animate({left: nextPos}, 250);
  });

   $(".nav").mouseleave(function() {

    activeSlide.stop().animate({left: startPos}, 250);
  });

});// end ready
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.stop()` when animating.

```
activeSlide.stop().
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `stop(true,false)` to `stop(true,false)`

```
$("#parent").hover(
    function () {
        submenu.stop(true, true).slideDown(600);
    },
    function () {
        submenu.stop(true, true).slideUp(600);
    });
```

`.stop()` first argument 'clears the queue' and second will make animation to 'jump to end'.

```
.stop([clearQueue],[]jumpToEnd)
```

Here is the link for more info: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: I think you want to say: Change stop(true,false) to stop(true,true). In your code you write right

Comment: Yes thats what i am saying.

Answer (score 0):

A simple change in your parent hover function

```
$("#parent").hover(
function() {
  submenu.stop(true, false).slideDown( 600);
},
 function() {
  submenu.stop(true, false).slideUp( 600).hide();
});
```

Used a hide function after slideup. Test it now please.